# Checking if a user is authenticated on the back-end in Node.js, and serving page with ui-router in Angular

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router, passport.js

I can't find any resources online for my particular case.

On the back-end I am using PassportJS in NodeJS to authenticate users.

When the user requests the `index` page, I want him to see his home page (similar to how facebook.com takes you to your personal feed) or a login page if he is not authenticated.

Instead of the server handling which page to send back, as I don't want the user to feel redirected, I want Angular UI-Router to handle it.

That is, when the user requests a page, I want UI-Router to handle which pages he sees.

Is there any way to do that? Preferably, a very simple way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use resolve in ui-router.

Lets say you have an Auth Service (in example, i am using $firebaseSimpleLogin) You can define your on factory.

```
.factory('Auth', function ($firebaseSimpleLogin, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope, $firebase) {
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

var Auth = {
  register: function (user) {
    return auth.$createUser(user.email, user.password);
  },
  createProfile: function (user) {
    var profile = {
      username: user.username,
      md5_hash: user.md5_hash
    };

    var profileRef = $firebase(ref.child('profile'));
    return profileRef.$set(user.uid, profile);
  },
  login: function (user) {
    return auth.$login('password', user);
  },
  logout: function () {
    auth.$logout();
  },
  resolveUser: function() {
    return auth.$getCurrentUser();
  },
  signedIn: function() {
    return !!Auth.user.provider;
  },
  user: {}
};


$stateProvider
.state('TestPageCtrl', {
    url: 'testpage',
    templateUrl: 'test/testpage.html',
    controller: 'AuthCtrl',
    resolve: {
      user: function(Auth) {
        return Auth.resolveUser();
      }
    }
  });
```

So now using this user you can control access of user.

```
.controller('TestPageCtrl', function ($scope, $state, Auth, user) {
    if (user) {
        $state.go('posts');
    } else {
        // redirect to a page saying that login first.
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow awesome answer! Can I add a subquestion? Can I detect if my user authorized by looking for a cookie?

Comment: I think you will have to look into cookies based authentication. You will need to modify your service. Check this http://beletsky.net/2013/11/simple-authentication-in-angular-dot-js-app.html